# What is wrong with this MySQL command?

Tags: mysql, sql

The query that is throwing an error for my MySQL DB is:

```
SELECT t1.GROUPNAME FROM user_group t0, group t1 WHERE ((t0.users_USERNAME = 
?) AND (t1.GROUPNAME = t0.groups_GROUPNAME))
```

The error info is the following:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group t1 WHERE 
((t0.users_USERNAME = 'test') AND (t1.GROUPNAME = t0.groups_GROUP')
```

Okay so I know the problem is with the group t1 part. But I dont know what is wrong with it.

[Click here to see that I have all the needed colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKlEA.png)

Can any one find out what the problem could be here?

Comment: Calling a table `group` was a bad idea to begin with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` is a reserved word in SQL. You should put quotes around it.
Some JPA providers do that automatically, whereas others don't ...

Comment: Oh really? I never thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: Could you recommend a persistence provider that does use these brackets? Currently I am using eclipseLink

Comment: DataNucleus does auto-quote SQL keywords. Don't know what the others do